Change the Child componant button variant
How to Change the Child Button variant click on parent button click
GrantChild Example..............
import { api, LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class GrandChildCmp extends LightningElement {
  @api messageReceived;
  ButtonVariant;
  @api destructive='destructive';
  className='redBar';

  handleGrandChildSubmit() {
    if(this.destructive==='destructive')
        {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-api-reassignments
        this.destructive='success';
        }

this.messageSend = "From Grand Child Component";
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("grandchildevent", {
        detail: this.messageSend,
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true
      })
    );
  }
}

----------------------Child----------------------
import { api, LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class ChildCmp extends LightningElement {

  @api messageReceived;
  messageSend;
  @api destructive='destructive';

  handleChildSubmit() {
if(this.destructive==='destructive')
      {
      this.destructive='success';
 
      this.template.querySelector('c-grand-child-cmp[data-id="redBar"]').variant='destructive';
}
this.template.querySelector('c-grand-child-cmp').variant='destructive';
    this.messageSend = "From Child Component";
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("childevent", {
        detail: this.messageSend,
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true
      })
    );
  }

  handlegrandChildEvent(event) {
    this.messageReceived = event.detail;
  }
}


I think it will be helpful if you can include your html as well.
